# Why some commits are shown as committed "on GitHub"?

Tags: github, commit

I am just experimenting with GitHub.
Why some commits are shown as "committed on GitHub a day ago" and others as "committed a day ago"?

For example here:
https://github.com/apple/swift/commits/master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Committed on GitHub" means that this commit was created by GitHub on behalf of that user. That happens when you accept merge request via UI. You literally ask GitHub to create a commit for you.

You can also edit any file via the GitHub's UI. See this edit icon:

[image]

Such edit will be marked as "Committed on GitHub" as well.

If you look at the commit details you'll find that it has [two properties](https://asizikov.github.io/2015/11/03/abusing-github/) "Author" and "Committer". When they are different GitHub shows that in the UI.

Comment: I forked the spoon-knife back then, and now made new commits. Why do they appear differently? I have only used the online UI. (https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/pull/9633/commits)

Comment: The first commit "made changes that will shock the world" has your email as an Author and as a Committer. The others have your email as an Author and GitHub <noreply@github.com> as a Committer.

Comment: and the first one was made in March. Two options here: 1. You did it not via the web UI. 2. GitHub started to put noreply@github.com after only after that.

Comment: I think you are right. Before 10 June there is no "on GitHub" commit here https://github.com/apple/swift/commits/master?after=jmNwfOllNjU3viA9qz2Wy9mxiLcrNDgyMA==

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: It's pretty ugly tho. I hope there was a way to avoid it without the need of Git.